# Android Save and Restore Activity Context or Layout as Data

Tags: java, android, android-activity, instance, savestate

I have one design activity in which users can do so many things like add text and add an image.

Now I need to give an option to save their work as a draft, So all their context/relative layout is converted into data and saved to some file and it can be retrieved even after app close.

I cant use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState as I have many instances of the same activity.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
// Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
// Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}
```

So need to different method where I can click on Save button and store the instance state with a key and later click on Edit Button and get back the same instance with by passing a key

But need something like below

```
public void onSaveButtonClick(Bundle savedInstanceState, Sting Key)
{
   // save the activity to bundle with key and convert the bundle as data to store
}

public void onRestoreButtonClick(Bundle savedInstanceState, Sting Key)
{
    // convert the data to bindle and start the activity with restored bundle

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save data persistently, you can use SharedPreferences. This allows you the save data as key-value-pairs. Have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Note that SharedPreferences can handle only a limited set of data types.

Comment: shared preference can store int, string. Can I store entire activity state in shared preference?

Comment: Your state is also only a bundle of data, right? So even when you need to store more complex data, you can use for example Gson (https://github.com/google/gson) to convert your objects in their json representation and save that.

Comment: I am getting this error when I am trying to convert context. 
 E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make method constructor accessible

Comment: You should only save & restore the data you actually need. So for example, you can save the text that's inside an EditText as a String, and when restoring it, you can set the String as text to the EditText again. And you can write an image to a file, and save the path to that image. But saving a context and a complete layout is neither possible nor necessary.

Comment: I feel u r not getting me. I have ImageView also. User may add any number of text fields and images. So need  a method to save entire relative layout and all subview with hierarchy gets saved automatically

Comment: Oh ok, I think I got it now. View has two methods called saveHierarchyState and restoreHierarchyState. You can call those methods on your root view. Probably that's what you need. But I haven't work with that yet, so I'm afraid I can't tell you more about that.